# Forall and exists in a Coq proof

Tags: coq

Currently, I have in my theory the following axiom:

```
Axiom context_existence : forall s t a,
  F a s -> Ps t a -> exists u, C u s t.
```

When i use this axiom in a proof, I do like this:

```
pose proof (context_existence s t a Fas Psta) as (u & Cust).
```

However, as `a` is not used in the conclusion of my axiom, I rewrite the axiom like this:

```
Axiom context_existence : forall s t,
  (exists a, F a s /\ Ps t a) -> exists u, C u s t.
```

And as `(exists a, F a s /\ Ps t a)` has a meaning in my theory, I defined a predicate `Cb` like this:

```
Definition Cb s t := exists a, F a t /\ Ps s a.
```

And I rewrite my axiom like this:

```
Axiom context_existence : forall s t,
  Cb t s -> exists u, C u s t.
```

However, the proof become less direct. I do something like this:

```
pose proof (context_existence s t) as (u & Cust).
exists a; split; auto.
```

I know that if it was just the `and` I could do something like:

```
pose proof (context_existence s t (conj Fas Psta)) as (u & Cust).
```

However, there is the `exists` clause and I don’t know how to deal with it. Is there a way, like a function such as `conj`, that would enable me to do my proof in one line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I understand completely your question but here is my try.
As with `_/\_`, `exist` is not primitive in Coq, it is an inductive predicate defined this way :

```
Inductive ex (A : Type) (P : A -> Prop) : Prop :=
    ex_intro : forall x : A, P x -> exists y, P y.
ex_intro : forall [A : Type] (P : A -> Prop) (x : A), P x -> exists y, P y
Arguments ex [A]%type_scope P%function_scope
Arguments ex_intro [A]%type_scope P%function_scope x _
```

(This is printed with `Print ex.` and `About ex_intro.`)
There is one constructor called `ex_intro` taking

- a first implicit argument (the type `A` inferable from the context)
- a second argument : a predicate `P` on A
- a third argument : a witness `x : A`
- a fourth argument : a proof of `P x`

So, as with `conj`, you may manually construct proofs of `exists` formulas.

Here, this gives something like this:

```
  pose proof (context_existence s t
    (ex_intro _ a (conj Fas Psta))) as (u & Cu).
```

Notice that Coq was smart enough to infer from the proof of `(Fas /\ Psta)` of type `(F a s /\ Ps t a)` the predicate `(fun x => F x s /\ Ps x a)` which is quite interesting (we did not provide an explicit predicate, but left `_`). The same could be done for `a` here.

Comment: That’s exactly what I wanted. Thanks!